# Simplify function to find rate constants

Tags: function-construction, fitting, chemistry

I have a function to calculate rate constants using nonlinear least square modeling from a 2011 paper by Jia et al. https://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674(11)00536-8?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0092867411005368%3Fshowall%3Dtrue#sec4.7 that has taken over a day to solve one matrix. Any suggestions on how to simplify the code?

Defining parameters/reading table (with headers, the data is in a 30x6 table where there are 29 substrates and 5 times (from 0 to 20 minutes)):

```
j=29;j=j+1;
T=20;T=T+5;
data=Import["trial1.xlsx", "XLSX"]; 
A=data[[1]];
For[m=2,m<j+1,m++,Subscript[x,m-2]=A[[m]]; 
Subscript[data,m-2]=Table[{Time[[j]], Subscript[x,m-2][[j]]},{j,2,n}]];
```

Laplace transformation of the equation for pseudo-first order rate constants to calculate time constants[image] [image]

```
    For[u=1,u<j,u++,Subscript[g,u][t_]=Exp[-Subscript[k,u] t]; 
Subscript[G,u][s_]=LaplaceTransform[Subscript[g,u][t],t,s];];
    For[v=1,v<j-1,v++,Subscript[A,0][s_]=Subscript[G,1][s]; 
Subscript[A,v][s_]=Subscript[k,v] Subscript[G,v+1][s] Subscript[A,v- 1][s]; 
Subscript[a,0][t_]=InverseLaplaceTransform[Subscript[A,0][s],s,t]; 
Subscript[a,v][t_]=InverseLaplaceTransform[Subscript[A,v][s],s,t];]
```

Nonlinear least square modeling and printing table of rate constants:

```
    For[w=1,w<j,w++,Subscript[s,0]=NonlinearModelFit[Subscript[data,0],{Subscript[ a,0][t]},{Subscript[k,1]},t]; 
Rates=Table[Subscript[s,i-1][[1]],{i,1,w}]; 
Subscript[s,w]=NonlinearModelFit[Subscript[data,w],{Subscript[a,w][t]},{Subscript[k,w+1]},t]/.Rates];
    r=Table[{i,Subscript[k,i]},{i,1,j-1}]
    Print[r]\[IndentingNewLine]Export["trial1out.xls", r]
```

Comment: Please provide some simplified example. Imagine, people want to try and improve your code, but they do not have "trial1.xlsx". You do not need to provide your actual data, but you need to provide some to test the code.

Comment: If your data includes concentrations over time for all intermediate species, then it is probably simpler and likely also more robust to estimate the reaction rates using linear least squares.

Comment: FWIW, the authors of the paper indicate that they used Mathematica to perform their analysis - you might find the easiest route is to contact them and ask for their code. (although it was a while back, I understand).